# foursquare venues/suggestcompletion doesn`t support categories filter

Tags: foursquare

Currently the Suggest Completion Venues API doesn't support filtering the results by category IDs.  Is this planned or is there an alternative API?

Answer (score 1):

The suggest completion API does not support filtering by category IDs. You will have to do such filtering on the responses manually, or use a different endpoint.